# What's the differences between QCursor::pos() and event->globalPos()?

Tags: qt

```
wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    QPoint cursor = QCursor::pos();
    QPoint eventGlobal = event->globalPos();
}
```

Accroding to Qt document,QCursor::pos() returns position of the cursor (hot spot) of the primary screen in global screen coordinates. event->globalPos() returns the global position of the mouse pointer at the time of the event. What is different?

Comment: In fact, the values are very different with each other.

Comment: Different values ... e.g, mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()) could return negtive values, mapFromGlobal(event->globalPos()) will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event->globalPos() will return the position of the mouse in screen coordinates at the time you moved the wheel. QCursor::pos() will return the current position of the mouse in screen coordinates. So if you don't move the mouse too fast you should see the same value on both.

I said mouse here to be clear, but it can be any device that emits the wheel event and that is also the pointer. If the wheel event come from other kind of devices the numbers could be different too.

The event processing will happen after the event propagated though the event system and it takes time to do so, when you call QCursor::pos() you are just accessing the cursor position directly (or at least the most recent value obtained from the substem)

Comment: From my test ,if I have two monitors, the values are different, event  the wheel event is triggered on different position in one widget, the values could be same,but also could be  inconsistent.

Comment: Maybe you can share your test code, because in my systems (with dual monitors and single monitor) it works as expected.